# Creating selenium hub and multiple nodes with other systems and running browsers in all nodes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have created a hub in one system using

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub`

After creating the hub, I went to " http://127.x.x.1:4444/wd/hub ", it created a hub showing to create sessions but when I go to other LAN computer and run this command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub" http://127.x.x.1:4444"/wd/register
```

I get couldn't register the node:hub is down or not responding

what I exactly need is hub and 3 LAN nodes and to run a script which is in eclipse to open a link in multiple browsers in multiple systems when I run in hub.

please let me know how to do this.